# Нужно очистить текстовый файл и записать после очистки новые данные

Tags: java

Есть .txt файл, он должен с помощью кода очищаться, и после очищения в него нужно записать новую информацию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `OpenOption`, чтобы указать, на каких условиях хотите открыть файл.

```java
OpenOption[] oo4 = new OpenOption[] {StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.CREATE};
Path path4 = Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\oo4.txt");
try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(path4, oo4);
     PrintStream outps = new PrintStream(out);) {
    // какая-то запись в файл через outps
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

При этом содержимое файла очистится, даже если никакой записи в него не было. При использовании `... new OpenOption[] { StandardOpenOption.CREATE};` вместо `... new OpenOption[] {StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.CREATE};` содержимое файла очистится, только если хоть какая-нибудь запись в него была произведена.

Comment: у меня файл не отчистился `
      String phn3="C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\XobDanii.txt";
      OpenOption[] oo4 = new OpenOption[] {StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.CREATE};
      Path path4 = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\XobDanii.txt");
      try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(path4, oo4);
           PrintStream outps = new PrintStream(out);) {
       outps.println(content);`

Comment: Вы уверены, что верно смотрите на файл? Если он открыт в каком-то редакторе, то редактор может не видеть его нового состояния и т.д. Убедитесь, что никакой другой процесс файл не держит.